# How to display the Values of a Column as the labels for the Bar in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Hi I'm struggling trying to plot a Bar Chart in R.

I have a **Factor** with Categories and the Frequency for each category.
What I want to do is to display the Value of each category at the top of the bars, like when using:  `geom_text(aes(label = ..count..), stat = "count", vjust = 1.5)` but cannot use this function because it is for when plotting data frames.

> In this case I want to plot a Vector with *BarChart()* or *barplot()* and display the Values above the bars.
> A cool feature about BarChart() is that automatically displays the percentage values of the bars (%).

The Vector is about the Average Hours of Sleep of 24 individuals.

```
#1. load lessR library
library(lessR)

#2. create a vector with range categories 
sleep_hrs <- cut(avg_sleep$AvgHrsAsleep, breaks = c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12))

#3. use BarChart()
BarChart(BarChart(sleep_hrs, main = "Average Hours of Sleep by Ranges",
         xlab= "Average Sleep Hours", ylab="Individuals")
```

The Vector looks like this:

> sleep_hrs
> [0,2)   [2,4)   [4,6)   [6,8)  [8,10) [10,12)
> 2       1       5      13       2       1

The graph looks like this:

[BarChart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvmKA.png)

Another way I have tried to figure out is, creating a Data Frame of the *sleep_hrs* Vector, and trying to display the 2nd column of Frequencies, and then display those frequencies above the bars. ie. for the range: 6-8, the frequency is 13, how could I display this 13 above the bar?
The data frame would look like this:

```
ranges  freq
(0,2]   2  
(2,4]   1  
(4,6]   6  
(6,8]   13  
(8,10]  1  
(10,12] 1
```

This way I wouldn't need to use:
`geom_text(aes(label = ..count..), stat = "count", vjust = 1.5)`, because I already have the count, and just want to display that value

Any ideas or a different process would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (from a dataframe with at least one categorical variable).

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOp6X.png)

```
# Packages:
require(dplyr, lib = path_lib)
require(readr, lib = path_lib)
require(RColorBrewer, lib = path_lib)
require(ggplot2, lib = path_lib)

# Dataset:
df = readr::read_csv(paste0(path_data, "nasa_exoplanets.csv")) %>%
         as.data.frame()
attr(df, "spec") = NULL
df_varnames = readr::read_csv(paste0(path_data, "nasa_exoplanets_var_names.csv")) %>%
                  as.data.frame()
attr(df_varnames, "spec") = NULL

# Variables:
cat_var = "pl_tsystemref"
cat_var_name = (df_varnames %>%
                   dplyr::filter(var == cat_var))$var_name

# Adapt the data:
df_plot = df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(eval(parse(text = cat_var))) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(freq = n()) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    dplyr::arrange(desc(freq))
names(df_plot)[1] = "level"

# Deal with NA:
df_plot$level[which(is.na(df_plot$level))] = "NA"

# Levels order:
df_plot$level = factor(x = df_plot$level,
                       levels = unique(df_plot$level))

# Relative frequency:
df_plot$freq_rel = round(df_plot$freq/sum(df_plot$freq)*100,
                         digits = 3)
df_plot$freq_rel_char = paste0(df_plot$freq_rel, "%")

# Plot:
my_palette = colorRampPalette(c("#111539", "#97A1D9"))
p = ggplot(data = df_plot) + 
    geom_bar(
        aes(
            x = level,
            y = freq,
            fill = level
        ),
        stat = "identity",
        show.legend = FALSE
    ) +
    geom_text(aes(x = level, 
                  y = freq, 
                  label = freq),
              color = my_palette(3)[2],
              size = 7,
              vjust = -0.2) +
    scale_fill_manual(
        values = my_palette(nrow(df_plot))
    ) +
    theme(
        axis.text.x = element_text(
            size = 14,
            angle = 20, 
            hjust = 1,
            vjust = 1
        ),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title.x = element_text(
            size = 15,
            face = "bold"
        ),
        axis.title.y = element_text(
            size = 15,
            face = "bold"
        ),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(
            size = 0.2,
            linetype = "solid",
            colour = "#eaeaea"
        ),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(
            size = 0.1,
            linetype = "solid",
            colour = "#eaeaea"
        ),
        plot.margin = margin(
            t = 0, 
            r = 5,
            b = 5, 
            l = 10,
            unit = "pt"
        )
    ) +
    xlab(cat_var_name) +
    ylab("Frequency")

p
```